# Qt5: cross-compiling static program with evdev-support

Tags: c++, linux, cross-platform, qt5, evdev

I'm trying cross compiling a simple program. Natively compiling on my computer works (the program is functionable). When cross-compiling for my dev-board, linuxfb work out of the box. But no input is generated.

That's how qt was configured:

```
./configure -opensource -confirm-license -prefix /opt/qt5-armhf -static -no-qml-debug -xplatform armhf-g++ -no-gif -qt-libpng -no-libjpeg -no-openssl -no-cups -no-eglfs -no-directfb -qpa linuxfb -no-opengl -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

That's my .pro:

```
QT += widgets
DESTDIR     = bin
HEADERS     = src/mainwindow.h src/modules/RepartitionModule.h src/modules/ConfigModule.h
SOURCES     = src/main.cpp src/mainwindow.cpp src/modules/RepartitionModule.cpp
RESOURCES   = installer.qrc
QTPLUGIN   += qevdevkeyboardplugin qevdevmouseplugin
```

I'm getting following output at my dev board:

```
This plugin does not support setParent!
```

There seems no difference between starting the program using the -plugin EvdevXXX or parameters without. What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It should be `-plugin evdevXXX` instead of `-plugin EvdevXXX`.

Comment: Which kind of input device are you using ? And which is the entry in  `/dev/input ` ?